Troubleshooting Self-Signed and Programmatically Created Certificates: Private Key Management Issues
I have created a self-signed certificate and stored it in the personal certificates store. When I double-click on the certificate in mmc, it indicates 'You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate.'

However, when I right-click and select All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys, an error message appears saying, 'No key found for this certificate.'

Additionally, I have programmatically created an X.509 certificate and can use it to authenticate my service programmatically. My only issue is that when I click on All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys, I encounter the error. I want to use this option to access the permission details."
Can anyone throw some light what could have gone wrong in this case. Thanks in advance

which steps exactly did you made?

I have opened mmc as an admin , went to personal - certificates, selected my certificate and double-click on it. It shows "You have a private key corresponds to this certificate". When i right-click on the certificate 'All tasks' -> 'Manage Private keys' Im getting an error 'No keys found for certificate'. For me this is contradictory information. One says i have private key and another says no. what could be the possible reason

Pleas add new information always formatted to your questio. Comments are hard to read

I have found the solution, i was using X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeyset earlier , now changed to X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet and now it started working.
